# Pros & con of parallelizing task at higher vs lower level

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I have a Cherrypy server. Some of that server's job is to crunch data (let's call it *BigCalculation*) return the result to the client. The raw data is a numpy array (3 dims) and could ultimately be close to 1Gb in size. If performance is good it may even get bigger than that - so whatever I do needs to be scalable.

The results of *BigCalculation* that is typically returned to the client is a 2d image corresponding to different ways to slice the cube & compute some metrics on that slice. For now all this is done sequentially as a demo on smaller data cubes, but now I need to parallel it to some extent.

I'm thinking of a few ways I could go on about it. Conceptually, they range from low-level parallelism to a higher level:

- Something like Intel's [python distribution](https://software.intel.com/en-us/distribution-for-python). This is really low-level, but then assuming my code works fine on their distro I basically don't have to do anything.
- At the data level: I could split the initial cube into sections that are to be processed in parallele
- At the method level: a few such *BigCalculation* may be ongoing at the same time. Therefore I could spin each new *BigCalculation* in its own process.
- Server level: I'm also thinking I could spin off a sub-server that does only the calculations. The server instance that's exposed to the user only serves the requests and anything that has to do server-crunching is actually forward to a computation server.

My question: is there a best approach/practice when trying to decide the level **at which you implement parallel processing first**? Would I be better to implement lower-level parallelism first (e.g. Intel's or slicing my cube of data) or higher-level first (e.g. spin each call to *BigCalculation* seperately)? Or is it mostly something to be decided in specific instances and there is no general advice one can really give on this topic?

Comment: I am guessing you mean `GB` (i.e. gigabyte) where you write `Go` (Gigaoctet)?

Comment: edited. The point is that it's big enough to be thinking about it!

Comment: Although in fact, Go is probably the more precise term. You could have an OS with a byte size that isn't 8 bits - therefore the term "1Gb" could or not be equal to 1Go, whereas 1 Go is always the same amount of memory units.... (Maybe splitting hairs here...)